# Windows docker container sandbox.vhdx constantly expanding

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

We are seeing an issue with a subset of containers where the disk space used by a containers vhdx keeps increasing with time.  The increase is also constant with time, about 20GB per day.

When exec'ing into the container and inspecting how much space windows thinks is being used, we see no change between any two points in time - this has been checked with `Get-PsDrive` and `Get-ChildItem`

The applications running inside the container do produce logs that get forwarded to external drivers, and the docker containers themselves are also configured to do so.  We have confirmed that the logging drivers are working as expected.

Is there any other way to see what could be causing the vhdx to expand?

We are using docker engine 20.10.6 on windows 10.0.17763.4645

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install [SysInternals Process Monitor](http://live.sysinternals.com/Procmon64.exe) inside your container and apply a filter on file system writings in order to discover which process accesses the disk for writing.

Take in mind that a process which uses much disk space, and that then frees it, causes by the way a VHD enlargement.